# copy movie files from my external drive to my NAS

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch which copy movie files from my external drive to my NAS.
Filename looks like this:

**Bones S09E18 - Episodename**

Batch:

```
set FOLNAME="Bones\Recordings\"
set FILENAME="Bones "
@echo on
if exist %LPATH%%FILENAME%S09* (if not exist %NASPATH%%FOLNAME%"Season 9" mkdir %NASPATH%%FOLNAME%"Season 9")
copy /Y %LPATH%%FILENAME%S09* %NASPATH%%FOLNAME%"Season 9"
```

Currently I need to write the code for each Season.
Is it possible to get the season-number and use it as a variable in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at how I have split up the title from the Series and Episodes here.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%m in (*.mp4) do for %%i in (%%m) do for /f "tokens=1,*delims=SE-" %%a in ('echo %%i ^| findstr /R "S[0-9].E[0-9]."') do (
    set "File=%%m"
    set "remove=!File:*S%%aE%%b=!"
    call set "Title=%%File:!remove!=%%"
    echo File: "%%m" Movie Title: "!Title: S%%aE%%b=!" Season: "%%a" Episode: "%%b"
)
```

Note, I used `*.mp4` as an example to iterate through each mp4, just for demonstration purposes.

This is a bit more dynamic than having to manually specify the folder names. This purely `echo`'s the results to demonstrate.

Comment: Many thanks after necessary changes done, it does it's job.

Answer (score 0):

```
set "FOLNAME=Bones\Recordings"
set "FILENAME=Bones"
@echo on
for /L %%b in (0,1,9) do for /L %%c in (0,1,9) do (
 if exist "%LPATH%\%FILENAME% S%%b%%c*" (
  if %%b == 0 (
   mkdir "%NASPATH%\%FOLNAME%\Season %%c" 2>nul
   copy /Y "%LPATH%\%FILENAME% S%%b%%c*" "%NASPATH%\%FOLNAME%\Season %%c"
  ) else (
   mkdir "%NASPATH%\%FOLNAME%\Season %%b%%c" 2>nul
   copy /Y "%LPATH%\%FILENAME% S%%b%%c*" "%NASPATH%\%FOLNAME%\Season %%b%%c"
  )
 )
```

Tips : Use `set "var1=data"` for setting values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces in a batch file. Don't include the terminal `\` in directorynames - counterintuitively, it makes it easier to construct paths.

Simply vary `%%b` from 0 to 9 using a `for/L` (well - probably 1 to 2 would suffice) and `%%c` similarly, and construct the required names, inserting spaces, backslashes and quotes as required.

The `2>nul` suppresses error messages (eg. where the directory already exists). Appending `>nul` to the `copy` command would suppress the messages reporting the copies. Note `2>nul` because that's an errormessage and `>nul` as that's a normal message.